# Pointcut not well Formatted

Tags: java, spring, pointcuts

What is the format problem with this pointcut?

```
@Around("execution(* @myPackage.SafetyCritical.*(*))&& @annotation(deny)")
```

.i forgot to add: exception is "Pointcut is not well-formed: expecting 'name pattern' (last closing bracket before &&)

for an example the pointcut should work with this class:

```
@SafetyCritical
public class SecureClass
{

    public SecureClass(){

    }
    @Deny
    public void isNotAllowed(){
        System.out.println("This should not happen");

    }

    @Allow
    public void isAllowed(){
        System.out.println("Allowed");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***EDIT:***

I think the pointcut expression you are looking for would be more like this:

```
@Around("@target(myPackage.SafetyCritical) && @annotation(denyPackage.Deny)")
```

The `@target` designator is used to match classes that are marked with the given annoation, and the `@annotation` designator will filter to the methods annotated with the `denyPackage.Deny` annotation.

Again, a look through the [Spring Documentation regarding AspectJ support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj) would be helpful.

***ORIGINAL:***

To match on any number of arguments, the parameters definition passed to the `execution` pointcut designator should be '..'

```
@Around("execution(* myPackage.SafetyCritical.*(..)) && @annotation(deny)")
```

The [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj) has some examples of using this to denote accepting any number of arguments.

Also, I would venture to guess that that having the '@' symbol in front of your package name is not acceptable.  You should remove it.

Comment: Well, parsing exceptions can sometimes point you in the wrong direction.  Have you tried the suggestion?

Comment: yes i have. why did you left the "@" ? SafetyCritical is an annotation

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be trying to use an `execution` pointcut designator with an annotation.  The `execution` designator is for matching methods, and the `@annotation` designator should be restricting it to the `deny` annotation.  Can you give an example of the code you are trying to match with this expression?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a pointcut definition like this to match annotated methods:

```
@Around("execution(@myPackage.SafetyCritical * *(..)) && @annotation(deny)")
```

The last part `@annotation(deny)` (like you already know, but some others may not) is to bind the annotation to the advice method argument named "deny".

Edit: As per your update, I was not aware that SafetyCritical was an annotation on the class. I suppose that would be witin the target() goal then:

```
@Around("execution(* *(..)) && @target(myPackage.SafetyCritical) && @annotation(deny)")
```